# What does this rails form.submit syntax mean?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Im searching through a rails project and came across this syntax for the submit button of a form built using `forms_for`. I'm trying to

```
<%= f.submit t('activity.to_comment'), :class => "btn" %>
```

What does the `t` do here? I tried searching for a method name `to_comment` but couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`t` is an alias for the `translate` method. It's looking up the key `activity.to_comment` and returning whatever translation it finds.

Take a look at your `config/locales/en.yml` file. It most likely has an `activity` key with a `to_comment` item (something like `to_comment: Comment`).

This means that "Comment" would be output using the example above.

Answer (score 2):

It's a short form for `I18n#translate`.

What the method does is look up a translation in your internationalization files, located in `config/locales`.

Reference: [translate (ActionView::Helpers::TranslationHelper) - APIdock](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/TranslationHelper/translate)